# JSONDecodeError when convert OpenStreetMap query in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook, openstreetmap

I need help related to OpenStreetMap. I'm using python (jupyter notebook) to get data of hospitals in Bali area, Indonesia. Here is my code and query:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

overpass_api = "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"

query_hospital = """
[out:json];
{{geocodeArea:'Provinsi Bali'}}->.searchArea;
node[amenity='hospital'](area.searchArea);
out;
"""

response_hospital = requests.get(overpass_api, params={'data':query_hospital})
```

but when I run the next code,

```
data_hospital = response_hospital.json()
```

it returns error `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

the query works well in [Overpass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) but when I put in notebook, it returns error.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the request that works in the browser using the developer tools and check if your request is exactly the same?

Comment: I've tried the query in OSM API tool here https://overpass-turbo.eu/ and it works well. but when I run the same query in jupyter-notebook, it returns json response 400, means that the request is malformed / the the query syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. Looks like python can't parse the double curly braces {{ }} in the openstreetmap query. So I modify the query into like this

```
query_hospital = """
[out:json];
area[name=Bali];
node[amenity='hospital'](area);
out;
"""
```

or if we use area name in local language

```
query_hospital = """
[out:json];
area['name:id'='Provinsi Bali'];
node[amenity='hospital'](area);
out;
"""
```

the query returns same result and now python can parse it.